# Использование лицензии MIT в своём коммерческом проекте

Tags: веб-программирование, лицензирование

Можно ли мне переделать чужой продукт под лицензией MIT в своём коммерческом проекте?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно. Вот вам перевод MIT:

> Лицензия MIT
>
> Copyright © «год» «владельцы прав»
>
> Данная лицензия разрешает лицам, получившим копию данного программного обеспечения и сопутствующей документации (в дальнейшем именуемыми «Программное Обеспечение»), безвозмездно использовать Программное Обеспечение без ограничений, включая неограниченное право на использование, копирование, изменение, слияние, публикацию, распространение, сублицензирование и/или продажу копий Программного Обеспечения, а также лицам, которым предоставляется данное Программное Обеспечение, при соблюдении следующих условий:
>
> Указанное выше уведомление об авторском праве и данные условия должны быть включены во все копии или значимые части данного Программного Обеспечения.
>
> ДАННОЕ ПРОГРАММНОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ ПРЕДОСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ «КАК ЕСТЬ», БЕЗ КАКИХ-ЛИБО ГАРАНТИЙ, ЯВНО ВЫРАЖЕННЫХ ИЛИ ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЕМЫХ, ВКЛЮЧАЯ ГАРАНТИИ ТОВАРНОЙ ПРИГОДНОСТИ, СООТВЕТСТВИЯ ПО ЕГО КОНКРЕТНОМУ НАЗНАЧЕНИЮ И ОТСУТСТВИЯ НАРУШЕНИЙ, НО НЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЯСЬ ИМИ. НИ В КАКОМ СЛУЧАЕ АВТОРЫ ИЛИ ПРАВООБЛАДАТЕЛИ НЕ НЕСУТ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТИ ПО КАКИМ-ЛИБО ИСКАМ, ЗА УЩЕРБ ИЛИ ПО ИНЫМ ТРЕБОВАНИЯМ, В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ, ПРИ ДЕЙСТВИИ КОНТРАКТА, ДЕЛИКТЕ ИЛИ ИНОЙ СИТУАЦИИ, ВОЗНИКШИМ ИЗ-ЗА ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ ПРОГРАММНОГО ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЯ ИЛИ ИНЫХ ДЕЙСТВИЙ С ПРОГРАММНЫМ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕМ.

Ознакомьтесь с [статьей на habrahabr.ru о вашем вопросе](https://habrahabr.ru/post/310976/). Тут подробный разбор данной лицензии.